# How to add multiple rows to a binded dropdownlist using stored procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I did honestly searched this one thoroughly, but I guess I just don't ask the right question?

So, in my ASP.NET MVC project I have a database with many tables, plus stored procedures to view activ items.

E.g.

EmployesController.cs/Get Create:

```
List<VehiculeCompagnieActif> ListeVehiculeCompagnieActif = db.VehiculeCompagnieActif.OrderBy(vehicule => vehicule.DescriptionVehicule).ToList();
ViewBag.VehiculeCompagnie = new SelectList(ListeVehiculeCompagnieActif, "IdVehiculeCompagnie", "DescriptionVehicule");
```

Views/Employes/Create.cshtml:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VehiculeCompagnie, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VehiculeCompagnie,
                (SelectList)ViewBag.VehiculeCompagnie, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VehiculeCompagnie, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

So far so good, I have a functional dropdownlist with an optional empty label.
I need a second option to show, right after the first empty row to be "YES".
Basically, I need 2(two) optional labels.

I tried to add .Insert(0, "YES") like I saw in my searches right here:

```
List<VehiculeCompagnieActif> ListeVehiculeCompagnieActif = db.VehiculeCompagnieActif.OrderBy(vehicule => vehicule.DescriptionVehicule).ToList().Insert(0, "Yes");
```

But I get a messageError:
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Blablabla.Models.VehiculeActif'

I played a little bit with it: .Insert(0,0); and (0, null); but of course VisualStudio got no sense of humour. Obviously, I can not hard code the dropdownlist, since this list must be dynamic.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can inset by creating instance of type `VehiculeActif`

```
 ListeVehiculeCompagnieActif.Insert(0, new VehiculeCompagnieActif() {DescriptionVehicule = "Yes"});
 ListeVehiculeCompagnieActif.Insert(1, new VehiculeCompagnieActif() {DescriptionVehicule = "No" });
```

because when ever you create a list e.g

```
List<VehiculeCompagnieActif> list = new  List<VehiculeCompagnieActif>();
```

every item in the list will be of type `VehiculeCompagnieActif` that is why it was giving exception

Comment: Usman, you are a real man! It worked and I will be forever thankfull for your help. I wish you and your family good health!

Comment: thanks you can accept my answer if you dont know how check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work good luck